# Retrieve data from List<ObservableCollection> using for loop to insert every element in database

Tags: c#, mysql, observablecollection

I am playing with ObservableCollection first time. I am getting data from object of List of ObservableCollection in *uploadEventCalendar* HttpPost method in Web Api Project. Now I need to retrieve all elements and put it in MySql Database using single query. I have following things ready with me.

```
public class ModelEventCalendar
    {
        public string Occasion { get; set; }
        public string OccasionDate { get; set; }
        public string OccasionWeekDay { get; set; }
    }
[HttpPost]
        public string uploadEventCalendar(List<ModelEventCalendar> events)
        {
            query = "truncate table holiday_calendar;";//Removed old entries
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            conn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();

            for(int i = 0; i < events.Count; i++)
            {
                  // Here I wan't to get all elements of collection and insert it in holiday_calendar table. How to do?
            }

            return string.Format("Calendar Upload is Successful!");
        }
```